# Forwarding intializer list / aggregate inialization to std::array member

Tags: c++, c++14, initializer-list, stdarray

I have a class that encapsulates a stl compatible container type which is the only class member and gives a lot of vector math functions that can be applied on this vector.

This class has various kinds of constructors, one of them is a constructor that takes an initialiser list:

```
template <class Type, class VectorType = std::vector<Type>>
class MathVector
{
public:
    using initializer_list = std::initializer_list<Type>;

    MathVector (initializer_list il) : vector(il) {}

    // many more constructors and member functions here

private:
    VectorType vector:
}
```

While something like `MathVector<int> foo = { 1, 2, 3 }` works well, `MathVector<int, std::array<int, 3>> bar = { 1, 2, 3 }` fails to compile on clang with an error like

```
(86, 55) No matching constructor for initialization of 'std::__1::array<int, 3>'
```

`std::vector<int> foo = { 1, 2, 3 }` and `std::array<int, 3> bar = { 1, 2, 3 }` works, so I guess that despite the same syntax, `std::array` is not really constructed through an initializer list in this case. This guess gets stronger when looking into the std library sources where I don't find any initializer list based `std::array` constructor. Furthermore, [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) tells me that *it can be initialized with [aggregate-initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization)* – which does not even seem to be any kind of usual constructor. So is there a way to create a constructor for my class that correctly forwards an initialization with the desired syntax to a `std::array` member?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With tag-dispatching:

```
template <typename T>
struct type_identity { using type = T; };

template <typename Type, typename VectorType = std::vector<Type>>
class MathVector
{
public:
    MathVector(std::initializer_list<Type> il)
        : MathVector(il, type_identity<VectorType>{}) {}

private:
    template <typename T>
    MathVector(std::initializer_list<Type> il, type_identity<T>)
        : vector(il) {}

    template <typename T, std::size_t N>
    MathVector(std::initializer_list<Type> il, type_identity<std::array<T, N>>)
        : MathVector(il, std::make_index_sequence<N>{}) {}

    template <std::size_t... Is>
    MathVector(std::initializer_list<Type> il, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
        : vector{ *(il.begin() + Is)... } {}

    VectorType vector;
};
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cc396da297af330b)

---

An alternative solution is to use a variadic template constructor.

```
template <typename Type, typename VectorType = std::vector<Type>>
class MathVector
{
public:
    template <typename... Ts>
    MathVector(Ts&&... ts)
        : vector{ std::forward<Ts>(ts)... } {}

    MathVector(MathVector& rhs)
        : MathVector(const_cast<const MathVector&>(rhs)) {}

    MathVector(const MathVector& rhs)
        : vector(rhs.vector) {}

private:
    VectorType vector;
};
```

[**DEMO 2**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/86efea26d223b596)

or shorter in [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20):

```
template <typename Type, typename VectorType = std::vector<Type>>
class MathVector
{
public:
    MathVector(std::convertible_to<Type> auto&&... ts)
        : vector{ std::forward<decltype(ts)>(ts)... } {}

private:
    VectorType vector;
};
```

[**DEMO 3**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/jMiERhjoEnQQTBag)